# Add Logout Button To be visible everywhere in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, user-interface, user-experience

I am building an iPhone application that requires the user to enter his credentials in order to use the application and can sign out in any moment.

I have used `UITabBarController` to navigate through my views, now I need to add a Logout button in a way that it is available/visible all the time.

Can anybody suggest a solution or best practice for this case?

Comment: Do you want this to display a view or act like a button that logs the user out without a view?

Comment: It will direct the user back to the login view

Comment: Does this need to be different than the standard UITabBarController setup? Why can't you just add a logout button to the tab bar?

Comment: I have thought about that do you think it's the best user user-experience here?

Comment: It's hard to say without having a better idea of what you're doing and seeing your UI layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you spare a tab bar item for that? It seems like the most clean way. Then you can use

```
  tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

method of the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

something like this (assuming that the logout tab is the 5th tab)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 4) {

        //LOGOUT
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, close to what `j0k` said.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the Right Button Position for it.

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(yourLogoutSelector)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
[saveButton release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Did you try using your Navigation Controller as your *root Controller* ? You can use the rightBarButtonItem for Logging out.